# java spring mysql 1000 tranactions per second interferes each other

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions

I have the following logic:

```
1. Check if A in DB
2. If not, insert A.
```

This method has @Transactional annotation, and it works. But, when I have 1k requests per second, with the same A, the second request can't see A, and only Nth request starts to see A. How to make them see A right starting from the second request? Performance is very important. Requests are coming in many different threads. How to make them see the change of the first insert A in all further requests?

Comment: are you using thread? actually better to ask ...is it synch or asynch?

Comment: You're stating that request are coming in many different threads. Unless you serialize those requests (using a single connection), waiting for the pending transaction to be committed, before sending a new request, it is normal to see some delay before new values are available to all connections.

Comment: Thanks, I use just threadpoolexecutor. The issue is I need to have the result immediately. And also, I start 10 transactions in 10 threads, how to wait for them?

Comment: MySQL offers INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE queries for precisely this purpose. I don't know to invoke them with Spring though.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to know how to solve it on DB level. Ideally I'd like to have ability to wait for transaction which inserts value '123' on db server, independently on where that transaction came from.